# Is there any alternative for embedding a.swf file except <EMBED> tag?

Tags: html

I made a page in which I used embed tag to embed a .swf file but sometime it creates problem in firefox, is there any other tag which I can use instead of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can even use iframe for that ni this way:

```
<iframe src="location/name.swf" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the [`object`](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_object.asp) tag!